# Credit/debit card machine to send bill to mobile app after payment

Tags: wireless, data-transfer, mobile-applications

Hi all I'm totally new to iot, I just wanted to know if it's possible to send the bill from a credit/debit card machine to a mobile app after a payment, would to be possible, if yes any specific article steps I can follow  any information will be immensley helpful

Thank you

Comment: Can you clarify exactly what you want to do? There are many app-controlled card readers (like Square, SumUp, and more). An app could also be interfaces with a system receiving notifications of payments on the merchant account. There are probably quite a few other possibilities but it depends a lot on what you want to achieve.